# Airflow - Branching join operators

Tags: python, branch, airflow

I am trying to join branching operators in Airflow

I did this :

```
op1>>[op2,op3,op4]
op2>>op5
op3>>op6
op4>>op7
[op5,op6,op7]>>op8
```

It gives a schema like this with relations between op2, op3, op4 and op8.

[image: current airflow dag]

How do I get this:

[image: desired airflow dag]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you be more clear ? I tried using your chain function and I can do what you wanted. [image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all: can you be more specific as to the exact code you use to set the relationships between the tasks?

Second: you could try using the [chain function](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#relationship-builders). If you look at the last example in the relationship-builders section, that should be pretty much what you are trying to achieve right?

Third: you can use [airflow show_dag](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/cli.html#show_dag) to easily visualize your dag.